# MySQL select from multiple vertical tables and display horizontally

Tags: mysql, select, horizontallist

I have the following 4 tables:

```
account           sub                   sub_props         sub_prop_vals
|id|number|       |id|account_id|       |id|sub_id|       |id|key|value|
|01|123456|       |02|01|               |03|02|           |03|notifMethod|SM|
                                        |04|02|           |04|notifStatus|true| 
|02|234567|       |03|02|               |05|03|           |05|notifStatus|true|
|03|345678|       |04|03|               |06|04|           |06|notifMethod|EM|
                                        |07|04|           |07|notifStatus|false|
```

Should display:

```
number;account_id;notifMethod;notifStatus
123456;01;SM;true
234567;02;null;true
345678;03;EM;false
```

I want data from all tables displayed in a single horizontal line per account.number and sub.account_id. I have tried something along these lines but it doesn't correctly show values based on my cases. The query will create one row per "hit" from my cases.

```
select
ac.number,
ss.account_id,
case
   when spv.key = 'notifMethod' and spv.value = 'SM' then 'SM'
   when spv.key = 'notifMethod' and spv.value = 'EM' then 'EM'
end as notifMethod,
case
   when spv.key = 'notifStatus' and spv.value = 'Enabled' the 'true'
   when spv.key = 'notifStatus' and spv.value = 'Disabled' then 'false'
end as notifStatus
from account ac
inner join sub ss on ac.id = ss.account_id
inner join sub_props sp on ss.id = sp.sub_id
inner join sub_prop_vals spv on sp.id = spv.id
group by ac.number, sub.account_id;
```

Comment: MAX(case..) notifmethod ?

Comment: MAX(case..) is the trick indeed! Thank you Strawberry.